# Android "Permission Failure"

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I'm working on a system level app for Android (minSdk=20, targetSdk=22).

I need to grant the `android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING` permission, which I add to my manifest. However, at runtime I get an error:

```
06-30 03:33:45.972 W/ServiceManager(  237): Permission failure: android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING from uid=10004 pid=15076
06-30 03:33:45.972 E/empty   (  237): android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_ROUTING
```

I tried modifying the permission's `android:protectionLevel` to use `signature|privileged` as seen [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#3772), but that didn't compile. So I changed it to `signatureOrSystem` (which is the new API) described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element). This builds, but still doesn't work. Is there some other magic I need to get this permission?

Comment: If this is an open-source project, could you say what is that you'll do with that permission? I found almost nothing about it but could be useful in trying to put my assistant talking in a phone call instead of me. Just have no idea of any examples or documentation of it, so no idea how it would be used. Did you find anything to help you with it? (If you can say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reboot the device if you change a system level permission like this.